# Best way to create add borders on webpage html?

Tags: html, css

I want to make borders to be consistent throughout the pages. What do you think is the best method to do this? I have added an image below, I had in mind to have the red areas blank, cutting the menu borders and all the rest on the sides so it all looks aligned and centered. thanks a mil

[image]

https://jsfiddle.net/q97kob5b/

> HTML

```css
body {
font-family: verdana;
background: white;
color: black;
}
.menu_div {
background-color: #333;
width: 100%;
}
ul {
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0 auto;
display: table;
padding: 0;
z-index: 100;
overflow: hidden;
}
li {
float: left;
}
li a, .dropbtn {
display: inline-block;
color: white;
text-align: center;
padding: 14px 16px;
text-decoration: none;
}
li a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
background-color: black;
}
li.dropdown {
display: inline-block;
}
.dropdown-content {
display: none;
position: absolute;
background-color: #f9f9f9;
min-width: 160px;
box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
z-index: 100;
}
.dropdown-content a {
color: black;
padding: 12px 16px;
text-decoration: none;
display: block;
text-align: left;
}
.dropdown-content a:hover {
background-color: #f1f1f1
}
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
display: block;
}
 @keyframes fade {
 0% {
opacity: 0;
}
 11.11% {
opacity: 1;
}
 33.33% {
opacity: 1;
}
 44.44% {
opacity: 0;
}
 100% {
opacity: 0;
}
}
.fadein {
position: absolute;
height: 102px;
width: 50px;
outline: 1px solid blue;
}
.fadein img {
position: absolute;
left: 0;
right: 0;
opacity: 0;
animation-name: fade;
animation-duration: 9s;
animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
.fadein img:nth-child(1) {
animation-delay: 0s;
}
.fadein img:nth-child(2) {
animation-delay: 3s;
}
.fadein img:nth-child(3) {
animation-delay: 6s;
}
.menu_div {
position: relative;
z-index: 0;
border: dashed;
height: 2.9em;
margin-bottom: 0em;
margin-top: 0em;
z-index: 1000;
}
.fadein {
position: relative;
z-index: 3;
 background:;
width: 100%;
left: 1px;
top: 0em;
}
.fadein img {
margin: 0 auto;
width: 100%;
max-width: 4060px;
min-width: 900px;
max-height: 500%;
}
.tech-slideshow {
height: 200px;
max-width: 800px;
margin: 0 auto;
position: relative;
overflow: hidden;
transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
.tech-slideshow > div {
height: 100px;
width: 2526px;
background: url(https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/3/collage.jpg);
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
height: 100%;
transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
.tech-slideshow .mover-1 {
animation: moveSlideshow 12s linear infinite;
}
.tech-slideshow .mover-2 {
opacity: 0;
transition: opacity 0.5s ease-out;
background-position: 0 -200px;
animation: moveSlideshow 15s linear infinite;
}
.tech-slideshow:hover .mover-2 {
opacity: 1;
}
 @keyframes moveSlideshow {
 100% {
 transform: translateX(-66.6666%);
}
}
form {
background-color: #f7f7f7;
border: 2px solid black;
/* Just to center the form on the page */
margin: auto;
width: 1000px;
height: 500px;
/* To see the limits of the form */
padding: 7em;
border: 400px solid white;
border-radius: 10em;
}
div + div {
margin-top: 0.5em;
}
label {
/* To make sure that all label have the same size and are properly align */
display: inline-block;
width: 130px;
text-align: left;
}
input, textarea {
/* To make sure that all text field have the same font settings
     By default, textarea are set with a monospace font */
font: 0.9em verdana;
/* To give the same size to all text field */
width: 300px;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
/* To harmonize the look & feel of text field border */
border: 1px solid;
}
input:focus, textarea:focus {
/* To give a little highligh on active elements */
border-color: #000;
}
textarea {
  /* To properly align multiline text field with their label */
  vertical-align: top     
  /* To give enough room to type some text */
  height: 20em;
/* To allow users to resize any textarea vertically
     It works only on Chrome, Firefox and Safari */
resize: vertical;
}
.button {
/* To position the buttons to the same position of the text fields */
padding-left: 400px; /* same size as the label elements */
}
button {
/* This extra magin represent the same space as the space between
     the labels and their text fields */
margin-left: .4em;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Bewerbungsformular</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
<h1 align="center"> <a href="index.html"><img src="logo.png" alt="A.Willi A.G" /></a> </h1>
<div class="menu_div">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown"> <a href="#" class="dropbtn">Bewerber</a>
      <div class="dropdown-content"> <a href="#">Info</a> <a href="#">Jobs</a> </div>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropbtn">Kunde</a>
      <div class="dropdown-content"> <a href="personalverleih.html">Personalverleih</a> <a href="toolrental.html">Werkzeuge Mieten</a> <a href="referenzen.html">Referenzen</a> <a href="quali.html">Qulität, Sicherheit und Weiterbildung</a> </div>
    </li>
    <li><a href="kontakt.html">Kontakt</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="fadein"> <img src="welder1.png"> <img src="welder2.png"> <img src="welder3.png"> </div>
<div class="fadein img"> </div>
<form action="http://www.cs.tut.fi/cgi-bin/run/~jkorpela/echo.cgi" method="post">
<div>
  <h2>Bewerbungsformular</h2>
  <label for="name">Vorname*</label>
  <input type="text" id="name" name="user_name">
</div>
<div>
  <label for="mail">Nachname*</label>
  <input type="email" id="mail" name="user_email">
</div>
<div>
  <label for="msg">E-Mail*</label>
  <textarea id="msg" name="user_message"></textarea>
</div>
<div>
  <label for="msg">Telefon*</label>
  <textarea id="msg" name="user_message"></textarea>
</div>
<div>
  <label for="msg">Nationalität*</label>
  <textarea id="msg" name="user_message"></textarea>
</div>
<div>
  <label for="msg">Alter*</label>
  <textarea id="msg" name="user_message"></textarea>
</div>
<div>
  <label for="msg">Beruf*</label>
  <textarea id="msg" name="user_message"></textarea>
</div>
<div>
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  Lebenslauf oder Bewerbung und Beilagen*
  <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
  <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
</form>
</div>
<div class="button">
  <button type="submit">Send your message</button>
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to do this would be to wrap your content within a container, and set the max-width for this (70%) or so, then if you want to add borders to this container you can do so.

Add `<div class="container"`> before any content you want to be centered/contained, then close the div at the end, and add the following to your css:

```
.container {
  max-width: 70%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

Comment: i added the code now, do you think i formated it wrong? i added the div opening at the top of the page at content start and closed it at bottom. the contact form has gone abit haywire haha https://jsfiddle.net/vhkrLxc4/

Comment: ah maybe i added too much width on the contact, going to play with that. cheers for the help

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/2kwu2ouL/

Edited your HTML to make it a bit easier to work with, you'll want to get in to the habit of indenting content to make it easier to read. You had unneccessary width/height on the form so I changed this to auto, removed the 400px border which on the form which was causing a huge gap, you might want to play around with the border-radius etc. to get it similar to how you want, but this should be a good start for you

Comment: thanks rixcy appreciate the help, been learning coding for a week now and still have alot to learn haha.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your page inside a

```
<div id="wrapper">
    your content here
</div>


/* add this to css */
#wrapper {
    width:960px; /*put here the width you want*/
    margin: 0 auto;
}
/*-----*/
```

Comment: i added the code now, do you think i formated it wrong? i added the div opening at the top of the page at content start and closed it at bottom. the contact form has gone abit haywire haha jsfiddle.net/vhkrLxc4

Comment: ah maybe i added too much width on the contact, going to play with that. cheers for the help